# Powershell -like operator confusion

Tags: regex, powershell

Why does the following powershell code give false instead of true?

```
"ok" -like "??p*"
```

Comment: Read this: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_match.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `*` is a wildcard/glob and not a regex metacharacter.

Your pattern `??p*` isn't saying "any two characters followed by zero-or-more 'p' characters" it is saying "any two characters followed by a 'p' followed by anything".

Answer (score 2):

Your wildcard expression expect at least 3 characters with the third character being a p. As this is not the case the expression will return false.

See http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-wildcards.html